# Storing data in sessions

Tags: php, apache

I need some help regarding design issues. I have a web application running on Apache server,which contains a lot of information about users. Multiple pages uses various information from user table. Suppose the website is going to have a huge traffic. If I store the data in SESSION it is going to consume comparatively more space on server. If I use database access on different pages, it will increase I/O burst which is costly.
Is it good to store data as cookie on client's system? I can use JS and render output on various pages. Is there any pitfalls ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Session Variables: How much data is too much?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554990/session-variables-how-much-data-is-too-much)

Comment: I got the point reading your link. I have just one more doubt, what about storing in cookies informations like name , address, zip, city ? These details will be used during placing orders, can there be any problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution** - Your case is a perfect use case for in-memory caches. In-memory caches are caches which load data from DB at regular intervals.

**Why in-memory caches** - Your use case falls in between keeping information in session and in DB as you have mentioned. In-memory caches are ideal for such keeping such data.

**Basic points to take it forward**

- You need to store all your USER Table (and any other info which you need frequently) in this in-memory cache.
- The refresh interval (also known as sync interval) with the data in DB should be kept as per resource availability & traffic on your site. It can range from an hour to a day.
- You need to find out which is a good in-memory cache in PHP. I work with Java and `memcache` is one of the most popular in-memory caches in Java.

Comment: Thanks :) I did some minor grammar corrections. FWIW, both `memcache` and `memcached` is available for PHP, maybe `memcached` is more common.

Comment: I just want to point out not alot of sharehost has cache function enable,  although it is the fit case on using cache, please communicate with the sharehost before build things around it.